# How to stop patsy from creating redundant interactions of categorical variables

Tags: python, patsy

I'm using patsy to fit regressions with statsmodels using the formula api.

My problem is that my design matrix is singular because patsy creates (locally?) redundant interactions of categoricals.

```
import patsy
import pandas as pd
data = [('y',[2,5,6]),
        ('c1',['a','a','b']),
        ('c2',['g','f','g'])]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(data)#([y,c1,c2],columns=['y','c1','c2'])
formula = "y ~C(c1):C(c2)-1"
y,X = patsy.dmatrices(formula,df,return_type='dataframe')
print (X)

C(c1)[a]:C(c2)[f]   C(c1)[b]:C(c2)[f]   C(c1)[a]:C(c2)[g]   C(c1)[b]:C(c2)[g]
0   0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
1   1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

I would like to exclude the second column since `c1` doesn't have value `b` when `c2` has the value `f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patsy interprets `C(c1):C(c2)` as meaning "I want to estimate the effect of every combination of `c1` and `c2` values". If some of those combinations don't appear in your data, then they can't be estimated, so giving you a singular matrix at least points out the problem...

If you want to estimate effects for just the combinations that exist, one easy way is to make a new variable that takes on a different value for each combination of `c1` and `c2`. The reason this works is that patsy then will infer that the set of possible values is exactly the ones that actually appear -- it has no way to know that `b.f` could have happened:

```
In [1]: df["c1_and_c2"] = df["c1"] + "." + df["c2"]

In [2]: patsy.dmatrix("c1_and_c2 - 1", df)
Out[2]: 
DesignMatrix with shape (3, 3)
  c1_and_c2[a.f]  c1_and_c2[a.g]  c1_and_c2[b.g]
               0               1               0
               1               0               0
               0               0               1
  Terms:
    'c1_and_c2' (columns 0:3)
```